# How to use rest parameters in tuple?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 3 was appeared this opportunity to use rest parameters in tuple.

I tried this like:

```
type Coordinate = [number, number, ...number[]];

let coordinats: Coordinate;

coordinats = [1, 2, 3,4];

console.log(coordinats[2]);
```

Why `console.log(coordinats[2]);` does not return me 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Typescript types don't actually exist on runtime.  Typescript compiles to Javascript.  So what you typed:

```
type Coordinate = [number, number, ...number[]];

let coordinats: Coordinate;

coordinats = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(coordinats[2]);
```

Turns in to:

```
let coordinats;

coordinats = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(coordinats[2]);
```

So all `coordinats` is a number array.

All you're saying with the `Coordinate` type is that it's an array of numbers which have at least two values.  This gives you help on compile time errors when creating the array.

```
   let attempt1: Coordinate = []; // compile error
   let attempt2: Coordinate = [1]; // compile error
   let attempt3: Coordinate = [1, 2]; // works
```

The only way to retrieve the remaining numbers beyond the first two is to `slice` the array.

```
let remaining = coordinats.slice(2);
console.log(remaining);
```

If you want to enforce this behavior, then you would create your own class that wraps the array.

Answer (score 0):

And should it? If you know exactly there are two elements before the ellipsis, why not just call `coordinats.slice(2)`?

Comment: `console.log(coordinats[2]);` return only 3, why not both values?

Comment: Because 3 is the array's element at index 2; and if you log `coordinats[3]` it will print 4?